# UITableView - remove separator for "inactive" rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have screen similar to:
[image]

I want to remove separator below last "active" cell in tableView (in this case everything below "Kompozytorzy". How can i remove this separators?

I try to customize separators in `cellForRow:AtIndexPath:`, but everytime i change it this effect whole tableView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal behavior for a plain style table view with just a few rows. A simple solution is to provide an empty table footer:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a default behaviour in a UITableView, it fills the screen with empty rows.

What you can do is set an empty footer to your table:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{        
    return [[UIView alloc] init];
}
```

Or:

```
[self.myTableView setTableFooterView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
```